# Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I have created one dynamic web project project which is dependent on other project, means it using methods which is defined in dependent project, but while running it giving below error,

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/middle/WebSocketController
at com.test.backend.InsertData.run(InsertData.java:11)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.middle.WebSocketController
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
... 2 more
```

I have used separate thread for calling method from dependent Project.
I have also added the dependent project in Java Build Path. what should I do??

I have used Eclipse as IDE.

Comment: Make sure that you added all the required jars to the classpath.

Comment: Actually my one project is in Spring boot and second one is Dynamic web project, I have updated the pom.xml as per requirement.